# Return an array in jQuery map() function's callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I have a checkbox form control that can return multiple values per checkbox. I need the roles jQuery `map()` function to return an array of the values i.e. `[['administrator,manager'], [administrator,conatct]]`.

This question was answered however does not work for my implementation: 
[Using map function to get lists' data attributes into an array in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988443/using-map-function-to-get-lists-data-attributes-into-an-array-in-jquery).

```js
let roles = $('input.rolesHidden:checked').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get().join();

console.log(roles);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-check remove-user">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <p><label class="form-check-label" for="test.dev.webadd"></label><input name="groups" class="form-check-input remove-user-form" value="nis.test.dev.webadd" type="checkbox"> nis.test.dev.webadd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 text-left">
      <p><label class="form-check-label" for="test.dev.webadd"></label><input name="roles" class="rolesHidden" id="test.dev.webadd" value="administrator,manager" type="checkbox" checked='checked'> administrator,manager</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check remove-user">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <p><label class="form-check-label" for="test.dev.webadd2"></label><input name="groups" class="form-check-input remove-user-form" value="test.dev.webadd2" type="checkbox"> test.dev.webadd2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 text-left">
      <p><label class="form-check-label" for="test.dev.webadd2"></label><input name="roles" class="rolesHidden" id="test.dev.webadd2" value="contact,manager" type="checkbox" checked='checked'> contact,manager</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
output>> administrator,manager,contact,manager
```

I have tried wrapping `[this.value]` and like this `[[this.value]]`, however it just returns a single array of values.

Comment: You don't get `administrator,manager,contact,manager` as output with this code.

Comment: It already returns an array : if you remove the `.join` you get `['admin,mgr', 'admin,contact']` - ie an array with 2 entries.  Your stated "array of the values i.e" is actually an array of arrays where the inner array only ever has one value.

Comment: Converted to a snippet and changed typo `.join` to `.join()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `[[this.value]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4875669/1022914) and remove the `.join`.

```js
$(function() {
  let roles = $('input.rolesHidden:checked').map(function() {
    return [[this.value]];
  }).get();

  console.log(roles);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-check remove-user">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <p><label class="form-check-label" for="test.dev.webadd"></label><input name="groups" class="form-check-input remove-user-form" value="nis.test.dev.webadd" type="checkbox"> nis.test.dev.webadd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 text-left">
      <p><label class="form-check-label" for="test.dev.webadd"></label><input name="roles" class="rolesHidden" id="test.dev.webadd" value="administrator,manager" type="checkbox" checked> administrator,manager</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check remove-user">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <p><label class="form-check-label" for="test.dev.webadd2"></label><input name="groups" class="form-check-input remove-user-form" value="test.dev.webadd2" type="checkbox"> test.dev.webadd2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 text-left">
      <p><label class="form-check-label" for="test.dev.webadd2"></label><input name="roles" class="rolesHidden" id="test.dev.webadd2" value="contact,manager" type="checkbox" checked> contact,manager</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```